# Handling errors in Ren'py

Tags: error-handling, renpy

Im just getting started with this tool and I have absolutely no idea on why this doesn't work. Heres the full script:

```
# 이 파일에 게임 스크립트를 입력합니다.

# image 문을 사용해 이미지를 정의합니다.
# image eileen happy = "eileen_happy.png"

# 게임에서 사용할 캐릭터를 정의합니다.
define e = Character('아이린', color="#c8ffc8")


# 여기에서부터 게임이 시작합니다.
label start:

“Why arent u working”
```

And when I try to complie this, this screen pops up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because your korean-english language settings are using the wrong apostrophe. This happens when I switch Chinese to English. The apostrophe should be thin "" like that.